# Maintaining Gunicorn and flask on Unix

Tags: flask, gunicorn

I have flask app and starting that with gunicorn with 5 threads. I have two options so far to stop that running. Either grep for gunicorn and kill all 5 pids at once will kill command or pkill command.

But both are not what i am looking, especially with pkill, there are other applications running with same user id.

Anyone has a script I can use? Or an idea how I can implement?

Answer (score 0):

Gunicorn can write his [pid to a file](https://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html?highlight=pid#pidfile).

```
gunicorn ... -p /path/to/your/file/gunicorn.pid ...
```

Then you can run something like that to kill the application:

```sh
kill `cat /path/to/your/file/gunicorn.pid`
```

Comment: I don't want to feel so dumb here, can you explain me in detail if you don't mind.  Reason - I have installed gunicorn with pip install. The way I am running is, going to the virtual environment and then starting gunicorn, I am not specifying a location where it is.. So I am not sure where the config, pid etc are available.